# jquery slideToggle() on several classes

Tags: jquery, html-lists, slidetoggle

I have a list:

```
 ...
 <li>
      <a href="#" class="slide"></>Click me</a>
      <div class="newsitem">
           ...some content here
      </div>
 </li>
 <li>
      <a href="#" class="slide"></>Click me</a>
      <div class="newsitem">
           ...some content here
      </div>
 </li>
 ...
```

I want to use slideToggle like this:

```
$(".slide").click(function() {
     $(".newsitem").slideToggle("fast");
     return false;
});
```

The thing is, is that I want the different `slide` classes to just `slideToggle` the next `newsitem` class. I've tried using `.closest()`, `.nextSibling()` and so on.

A little help with this easy (probably) problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace:

```
$(".newsitem").slideToggle("fast");
```

With:

```
$(this).next(".newsitem").slideToggle('fast');
```

[Here](http://api.jquery.com/next/)'s the documentation for the next() method:

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/3DqNF/

**Also**, you had some invalid HTML.  Here's the corrected HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="slide">Click me</a>
        <div class="newsitem"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="slide">Click me</a>
        <div class="newsitem"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm and was exactly the kind of solution I wanted. I actually did the exact same thing but instead of next i used nextSibling() and that didnt work...

Comment: Well, i feel stupid. There isnt anything called nextSibling(), of course it didnt work :)

And I actually have the right HTML, was just too lazy to write out all the tags here. Thanks again

Comment: @Anders: I think the reason why `nextSibling()` (a DOM node property) was not working correctly is because it was actually getting the text node under the `<a>` tag that was clicked.  That is, when you clicked `<a>`, you were getting the text node containing "Click me".  Unintuitive, but that's a situation where jQuery helps out :).

Comment: @Anders: nextSibling() is a function, just not a jQuery function: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling

Answer (score -1):

hmm maybe this works:

```
$(".slide").each(function(){
  $(this).click(function() {
    $("this > .newsitem").slideToggle("fast");
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: That won't work because 'this' is not a relevant CSS selector.
You selection string would match an element with class 'newsitem' inside an element of type 'this'... of which there is no such element.

Comment: @dancrumb this would refer to the element passed by the each loop. So it should would be one of the .slide elements. But i thought the newsitem would be inside the .slide element, didnt look closely enough.

Comment: I was referring to the line $("this > .newsitem"). In this case "this" is just a string and not a reference to anything.